# How to create path for taxonomy term pages with parent terms if they exist

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a taxonomy vocabulary which will only ever contain 2 level deep hierarchy.

I need the url to be just [vocabulary]/[term] for any parent term.

But for a child term I need it to be the following

[vocabulary]/[parent_term]/[term]

Is this possible with a pathauto token? If not, is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pathauto token like this.

```
 [term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what will happen if the parent does not exist?

Comment: If parent does not exist then vocabulary/term name

Comment: You missed a "/" above

Comment: Sorry But I added screenshot.

Comment: I just wanted to say because for future people might get confused. Thanks